# Show that every group homomorphism can be written as a composition $ι ◦ π$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Show that every group homomorphism can be written as a composition $ι ◦ π$
of an injective group homomorphism $ι$ with a surjective group homomorphism $π$.
HINT: Use the first isomorphism theorem, aka the fundamental homomorphism
theorem.

I don't know how to start this proof.
If we have a group homomorphism $\phi : G \to H$, then surely $π : G \to X$ and $ι : X \to H$ ?

Comment: Yes, you have the correct domain and codomain for $\pi$ and $\iota$, but now you have to choose an $X$. Hint, use the first isomorphism theorem. The first isomorphism theorem says that $G/\ker{\phi}\to \text{im}{\phi}$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: See my https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3591092/403337

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\phi: G \to H$ be a group morphism. The (proof of the) first isomorphism theorem tells us that

$$\iota: G/\ker \phi \to H: g \ker \phi \mapsto \phi(g)$$

is a well-defined group morphism that is injective.

Consider the natural projection $$\pi: G \to G/\ker \phi: g \mapsto g \ker \phi$$ which is a surjection. Then

$$\phi= \iota \circ \pi$$

and we are done.